# Is it possible to refresh a property in Grails?

Tags: grails

In order to refresh a domain object i.e to re-read the data from database we do refresh().

```
def b = Book.get(1)
…
b.refresh()
```

I am wondering whether we can refresh a property of the domain.

Suppose i have bound params to Book object and suppose i want to unbind the author property from the book object then is it possible to achieve that?

Let's consider the Book is defined as

```
class Book {
   String title
   String author
   String category
}
```

Suppose I do bindData(bookInstance, params). This will bind to all properties. I want to unbind the author after bindData. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using `bookInstance.author = bookInstance.getPersistentValue('author')`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to exclude binding a particular property.

```
bindData(bookInstance, params, [exclude: 'author'])
```

will bind all of the `Book` properties except for those listed.

You can conversely use `include` to explicitly list which properties to bind from `params`.

```
bindData(bookInstance, params, [include: 'title', 'category'])
```